# Fill in missing values using climatology data except for current year

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day])[vars_rs].transform(lambda y: y.fillna(y.median()))
```

I am filling missing values in a dataframe with median values from climatology. The days range from Jan 1 2010 to Dec 31st 2016. However, I only want to fill in missing values for days before current date (say Oct 1st 2016). How do I modify the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm would be:

1. Get a part of the data frame which contains only rows filtered by date with a boolean mask
2. Perform required replacements on it
3. Append the rest of the initial data frame to the end of the resulting data frame.

Dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 2)),columns=['A', 'B'],index=pd.date_range('2000',periods=5,freq='M'))

            A   B
2000-01-31  0.0 0.0
2000-02-29  0.0 0.0
2000-03-31  0.0 0.0
2000-04-30  0.0 0.0
2000-05-31  0.0 0.0
```

The code

```
vars_rs = ['A', 'B']
mask = df.index < '2000-03-31'
early = df[mask]
early = early.groupby([early.index.month, early.index.day])[vars_rs].transform(lambda y: y.replace(0.0, 1))  # replace with your code
result = early.append(df[~mask])
```

So the result is

```
            A   B
2000-01-31  1.0 1.0
2000-02-29  1.0 1.0
2000-03-31  0.0 0.0
2000-04-30  0.0 0.0
2000-05-31  0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`, example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'C':[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
df.ix[:,'C'] = np.where((df.A != 'c')&(df.B < 4)&(pd.isnull(df.C)),-99,df.ix[:,'C'])
```

Like this you can directly modify the desired column using boolean expressions and all columns.

Original dataframe:

```
   A  B    C
0  a  1  1.0
1  a  2  NaN
2  b  3  NaN
3  b  4  NaN
4  c  5  NaN
5  c  6  NaN
```

Modified dataframe:

```
   A  B     C
0  a  1   1.0
1  a  2 -99.0
2  b  3 -99.0
3  b  4   NaN
4  c  5   NaN
5  c  6   NaN
```